# Why don't my desktop icons stay in place?

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop

When I move my desktop around and then turn my computer on the next day they won't stay in place. They should always stay where I put them.

Comment: Are you using more than one display?

Comment: No I am only using 1. It is a Dell 1707FP monitor.

Answer (score 0):

this may work

Right Click on desktop screen.
Place the cursor on View.
In drop down menu, select auto align and check.

Comment: Auto align lines up the icons in alphabetical order. Since I like to put icons where I like (e.g., put the recycle bin in the lower left corner), I have that turned off (unchecked).

Comment: I did that. My icons still will not stay in place.

Comment: Now they are working.